# ReportViewer10 - display extra lines around report and toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have created a web app that uses reportviewer 10.0.0.0 in VS2010 to render SSRS 2008 reports. The reports and toolbar do render, but they are displayed with weird layout. I see many unnecessary lines wrapped around the report as well as the toolbar (as shown in screenshot).  I ran out of ideas on how to fix this problem. Are there some settings I missed for the reportviewer that caused this? How can I fix this issue? Thank you.

aspx:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-  
Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%" 
ShowParameterPrompts="false" ShowPrintButton="true"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

code behind:

```
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(GlobalProperties.SSRSBasePath); // Report Server URL
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/" + folder_name + "/" + report_name; // Report Name
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're having the problem I had when I got started with ReportViewer.
Try looking at your css. Check to see if you have any borders and other formatting for all tables on the site set that may cause the issue.